# await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, async-await

trying to make a chrome extension that scrapes a website but it always scapes it before the content is fully loaded (tried after document read thing in manifest.json)

everytime that is getting called I am getting:

```
await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules
```

```
const sleepz = (ms = 0) => {
    return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
};

const finsh_minting_shit = async(profile,user_id_now) => {
  console.log("das huhn hat ein ei gelegt");
  await sleepz(4000);
  console.log("RuehrEi")
});

window.onload = function() {
  finsh_minting_shit(profile,user_id_now);
}
```

also tried:

```
await finsh_minting_shit(profile,user_id_now);
```

Comment: And what would be the question?

Comment: It sounds like the web site you are scraping is injecting content dynamically using JavaScript that doesn't settle out until well after DOMContentLoaded is fired. You need to put your delay prior to calling `finish_minting_shit()` - (great function name BTW :-0 )

Answer (score 0):

```
const sleepz = (ms = 0) => {
    return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
};

const finsh_minting_shit = async(profile,user_id_now) => {
  console.log("das huhn hat ein ei gelegt");
  console.log("RuehrEi")
});

window.onload = function() {
  await sleepz(4000);
  finsh_minting_shit(profile,user_id_now);
}
```